# One more "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "device_gclouddevice" does not exist"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I know there is a lot of post with this problem but somehow I can't find a solution for my problem.

## Configuration

Django 3.0.0
Python 3.6.9
Docker 19.03.5

## Issue

I have a class starting like below, nothing fancy.

```
    class PubSub:  
      test = GcloudDevice.objects.count()
```

I use this class via command line and it works perfectly if I comment the test variable.
BUT if I run the command line with this line I get:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "device_gclouddevice" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "device_gclouddevice".

The thing is I am able to create GcloudDevice and I can see it and managed it from the admin zone.

## Things I already tried

I deleted all my migrations, remove my db and its volume.
Recreated all again, still the same issue.

I tried after this to delete again the migration from my device app and migrate them on their own, still the same

If anyone can help me and also explain to me how is it possible that everything works on the admin ( I can see on the django-debug-toolbar that this request is passing :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count"
  FROM "device_gclouddevice
```

, HOW FRUSTRATING) but not from the command line I would be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was not that difficult but it took me some time to get it. (and some help).

Thing is I was trying to use Django ORM with a pure python command line.
To fix It I am creating a django command wich I can use with './manage.py MyCommand '.
This way I can use django's options and use it via command line.
Et voila